# How to get the content of an external <script> object without calling the src URL again?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, tampermonkey

There is a page like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://someserver/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://someserver/getJS?key=123456" ></script>
        ...
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

And the content of getJS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
}
```

The key is dynamically generated every time the page is loaded, like a session key. The script `http://someserver/getJS?key=` is only accessible once for each key. On the second access, it returns `NULL`. However, viewing from Developer Tools in Chrome, the content of `getJS` is cached in the Resources/Application panel.

My questions:

1. Using a GreaseMonkey script or snippet, how do you access the content of any **external** script object as String without calling the URL **again**?
2. In Chrome's DevTools, how do you access any script (and other objects) under the Resources/Application panel in a snippet?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do here, **exactly**?  What purpose does getting the script as a string serve?  All the functions in the script are callable from the page after the script loads at any time.

Comment: Currently I manually open the Resource panel, get to the getJS script, copy the key, paste it to my snippet, and run it.

Comment: There is only 1 function in getJS, the document.ready function. There is a key in the ready function. My greasemonkey script/snippet is actually a modified ready function, the key is needed as the function send something back to the server.

Comment: right, so this is a script that the developer (not you, I presume) designed to be only run a single time, when the page loads.  This script does something (what probably doesn't matter), and then returns some data to the server.  You want to use grease monkey to essentially **hijack** the script, run some different computations, and return something (probably unexpected) to the server.  Is that about right?

Comment: it seems like the script in question is an [iife](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8228308/2495283), meaning that it is immediately invoked after it is created.  see also: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/32226159/2495283

Comment: Yep man, exactly!

Comment: you should probably tag greasemonkey or tampermonkey, because without one of those tools, you'll really not be able to re-execute an iife.

Comment: also it would be nice if more people read questions like this and could see that this kind of "security measure" isn't really secure at all.....

Comment: Right, I added greasemonkey to the tags just now.

Comment: read the guidance for that tag: "OBSOLETE as of Firefox 57. Use [greasemonkey-4] or [tampermonkey] as applicable. If using some other browser userscript engine, use [userscripts].".

Comment: Link to the actual site.  And if it doesn't violate the TOS, we may help you do this.

Comment: Thanks, but actually this is more like a generic question about javascript object scope and the use of devtools?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I'm interpreting your question correctly, but if you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do... You can use Javascript to dynamically create a `<script>` element, change its `src` property, and append it to the DOM.

```js
(function() {
  var body             = document.querySelector('body');
  var externalScript   = body.createElement('script');
  externalScript.src   = "https://host.com/script.js";
  document.body.appendChild(externalScript);
})()
```

Comment: This probably works if the external script is really https://host.com/script.js but not https://host.com/script.js?key=<some-dynamically-generated-key>, plus the script.js only return once for each key.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. My mistake.